# Cardboard Project

Tags: android, google-cardboard

Me and a group of friends are trying to build an android app that utilizes Cardboard.

We'd like to make something similar to that of the Google Cardboard app without the camera, only the viewing part. Basically, an app with pre-taken panorama images (using the Google Cardboard app) and then you could view them on a cardboard.

Problem is, we don't know where to begin aside from the sample cardboard project Treasure Hunt and that we are totally new to Cardboard and a little bit of experience with Android Development (on Unity: none). Can anyone lead us to somewhere where we can begin?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html ? or https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java ?

Comment: Your question is rather broad, which makes it not well-suited for Stack Overflow. Have you considered reading a book on VR development for Google Cardboard?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'd like to recreate the Cardboard app but without the camera module. Viewing only.

Comment: @Alexsanity which basically means you want an VR app not AR app. Which makes the previous CommonsWare's suggestion absolutely valid ;) The best way to do it is look at samples, run them and see that they cover all the functionality you need. Good luck

Comment: @Sam I found this https://vr.chromeexperiments.com/ and I'd like the example shown here (top). I'd like to make a similar one but for mobile using Android Studio. Can't seem to find ones with codes though

Comment: How about a 360 panorama viewer instead? I can probably start there and then do some other stuff so I can view it on a cardboard.